# SQL JOIN only if

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I have this query:

```
    SELECT 
    PS.ID,
    PS.Descricao,
    P.Nome_Razao,
    PS.Barra, 
    PV.ValorVenda
FROM 
    Produto_Servico PS
    INNER JOIN Produto_Valor PV ON PS.ID = PV.ID_Produto
    INNER JOIN Produto_Fornecedor PDF ON PS.ID = PDF.ID_Produto
    Right JOIN Pessoa P ON PDF.ID_Fornecedor = P.ID_Pessoa
WHERE 
    P.TipoPessoa = 3
```

The result is:

```
ID          Descricao                 Nome_Razao                              Barra               ValorVenda
----------- ------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------- -------------
NULL        NULL                      GDOOR SISTEMAS LTDA - EPP               NULL                NULL
NULL        NULL                      MIGRO SERVIÇOS DE INFORMATIC            NULL                NULL
20          SAT SWEDA SS-2000         SWEDA INFORMATICA                       7896118100960       0.00
NULL        NULL                      NET SERVIÇOS                            NULL                NULL
```

only the `ID` 20 has a value for the column `Nome_Razao` but instead of it returning `NULL` for the other `ID`s that do not have one `Nome_Razao` it returns all my records from the `Person` table where the `ID` is 3, what I would like is for the values ​​to return normally and that `ID`s that don't have a value for the column `Nome_Razao` would return `NULL` only in it.

Comment: There is no matching record in PS, so there is no value.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to change your RIGHT JOIN to a LEFT JOIN, and move the p.toipopessoa = 3 into the ON clause...

```
SELECT 
    PS.ID,
    PS.Descricao,
    P.Nome_Razao,
    PS.Barra, 
    PV.ValorVenda
FROM 
    Produto_Servico PS
    INNER JOIN Produto_Valor PV ON PS.ID = PV.ID_Produto
    INNER JOIN Produto_Fornecedor PDF ON PS.ID = PDF.ID_Produto
    LEFT JOIN Pessoa P 
    ON 
      PDF.ID_Fornecedor = P.ID_Pessoa AND
      P.TipoPessoa = 3
```

This will return all records from produto_* and also only those records from `pessoa` where 1) `tipopessoa = 3` and 2) the `id_pessoa` matches `id_fornecedor`